# Looping through controls on a page using a masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to perform an operation on every control on a page that is inherited from a masterpage.  I don't know how to access the child pages controls.  I have tried recursively getting to my controls like this:

```
    private void checkControls(ControlCollection controlcollection)
   {

    foreach (Control control in controlcollection)
    {
        if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(control.GetType().ToString());
            checkControls(control.Controls);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(control.GetType().ToString());
        }

    }
```

The method is called like this:

```
protected void resettodefault()
{
    checkControls(this.Page.Controls);
}
```

However, the only controls that are printed from this execution are:

```
ASP.site_master

System.Web.UI.LiteralControl
```

I would prefer to access my controls directly (without recursion).  Otherwise, how can I modify my recursion to get to the desired page's controls?

Comment: How is that function recursive? It does not call itself.

Comment: Typo on my end - good catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a base page instead of a master page, this way your logic for iterating over controls (and whatever you will do with that afterwards) is not tied to which master page a page is using.

As far as getting all the controls on the page, because the controls are hierarchical, as is the HTML they represent, so iterating over them recursively makes sense. However if you are dead set on not recursively getting controls something like this should work:

```
IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls()
{
    var allControls = new List<Control>();
    var currentControls = new Queue<Control>();
    currentControls.Enqueue(this.Page);

    while (currentControls.Count >0)
    {
        var c = currentControls.Dequeue();
        if (!allControls.Contains(c))
        {
            allControls.Add(c);
            if (c.Controls != null && c.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Control e in c.Controls)
                {
                    currentControls.Enqueue(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return allControls;
}
```

The last thing to consider is the lifecycle of the page, and when you iterate over the controls. If you try to walk to control tree too early not all controls may exist.

EDIT: Updated code.

**Update**

For validation purposes I would highly recommend using the built in validation controls of asp.net. You can read more about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z2h4sw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This has the added benefit of providing validation on the client, providing faster UI responses and easing the load off the servers.

For resetting all the textboxes. I would recommend creating a new class for this purpose, then calling upon that class when needed instead of messing with the master page:

```
public class UIControlsHelper
{
    public static void ClearTextboxes(Page page)
    {
        GetAllControls(page)
            .Where(x => typeof(TextBox).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType())
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => (TextBox)x.Text = string.Empty);

    }

    IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Page page)
      // Same as above, but with the page parameter replaced.
    }
}
```

And in any of your pages:

```
UIControlsHelper.ClearTextboxes(this);
```

Comment: That's a pretty cool use of queues - thanks for that, as well as the reference on base page.  I probably should have been more clear, the problem I'm running into when I loop through controls (recursively or iteratively) is that I'm only getting "ASP.site_master" as well as "System.Web.UI.LiteralControl" back.  Site_master occurs on the initial call, the LiteralControl is on the second call, and the function ends after that.  Any ideas on why this is?

Comment: What are you expecting as results?

Comment: I have two separate goals that I'm using this for..one is a 'clear all' button that simply clears every textbox on this page.  Another is a validation that checks every textbox for a null value and alerts the user if a textbox has been left null.  I can hardcode in the checks and validation, however, there's 15 textboxes - I'd like to find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

To access the controls in your child page do the following steps:

1-declare a variable of the type you want to access. For example if you want to access a Label in your child page use:

```
Label lbl_child=this.ContentPlaceHolder1.findcontrol("your label id in child page") as Label;
```

Now you have your label and you are free to make changes on it. Every change on this control will be reflected on the child control.

ContentPlaceHolder1 is your contentplace holder id so change it with your content id.

Comment: The OP is trying to do this without hard coding control names.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void ClearTextboxes(Page page) {
  GetAllControls(page)
    .Where(x => typeof(TextBox).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => ((TextBox)x).Enabled=false);
}
```

Comment: Please add explanations in your answer